# how to chain the existential operator in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Let's say that I have an object reference as follows in coffeescript:

```
object.param.foo.bar
```

and I want to validate that bar exists? How do I do that?

I believe that `object.param.foo?.bar` tests for the existence of `foo`, returning `undefined` if it does not exist, but that `object.param.foo.bar?` converts the entire expression into a boolean test.

What I want is something that returns `object.param.foo.bar` if it exists and `undefined` if it does not.

Comment: but `object.param.foo.bar` already  returns the value if it exists, and undefined if it doesn't...

Comment: Please clarify your question. In what way is `object.param.foo?.bar` not doing what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for the expression

```
object.param?.foo?.bar
```

which assumes that `object` exists, and will return `undefined` if either the `.param`, `.foo`, or `.bar` properties don't exist. You can omit `?`s if you know they do exist.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question (how does `object.param.foo?.bar` not do what you want? you haven't told us.).

But if you want to perform null checks the whole way (in case `object`, `object.param` or `object.param.bar` is null), you can use:

```
bar = object?.param?.foo?.bar
```

This will produce `undefined` if anything along this chain is null or undefined, and the value of `object.param.foo.bar` if it exists.